# Oracle Tree Structure Hierarchy Data Display in Single Row Different Column

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical table named **Employee_Hierarchy** in oracle with column names **entity_code**, **parent_entity_code**, entity_name and entity_role with no cycle.
Having lower most child in other table named **Client** connected with hierarchical table's lower most child with entity_code.
I have to display the data in single row hierarchy where column name will be appended by role.

**Sample Example:**

***Tree Structure:***

[image]

***Hierarchical Table:***

[image]

***Lower Most Child's Table:***

[image]

***Expected Result:***

[image]

Is there a way to get the expected result through oracle query?
And the expected result depends on input that means it will not always start from root element, it may start from any node for example team-lead (Shail) to lowermost child.

(**Note**:If a upper hierachy is missing then the parent_code of the current node will be its upper hierarchy's parent_code And the missing hierarchy element will be blank in expected result.)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This assumes a fixed number of levels in the hierarchy: Client < Developer < Team_Lead < Manager. Is that guaranteed by the business rules? Also, is a Client always linked to a Developer (and not, for example, directly to a Team_Lead)?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Probably different answers.)

Comment: @jarlh: I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select      h.Manager_entity_code  
           ,h.Manager_entity_name  
           ,h.Team_Lead_entity_code
           ,h.Team_Lead_entity_name
           ,h.Developer_entity_code
           ,h.Developer_entity_name
           ,c.client_name

from       (select      trim (both ',' from sys_connect_by_path (case when entity_role = 'Manager'   then entity_code end,','))  as Manager_entity_code
                       ,trim (both ',' from sys_connect_by_path (case when entity_role = 'Manager'   then entity_name end,','))  as Manager_entity_name
                       ,trim (both ',' from sys_connect_by_path (case when entity_role = 'Team-Lead' then entity_code end,','))  as Team_Lead_entity_code
                       ,trim (both ',' from sys_connect_by_path (case when entity_role = 'Team-Lead' then entity_name end,','))  as Team_Lead_entity_name
                       ,trim (both ',' from sys_connect_by_path (case when entity_role = 'Developer' then entity_code end,','))  as Developer_entity_code
                       ,trim (both ',' from sys_connect_by_path (case when entity_role = 'Developer' then entity_name end,','))  as Developer_entity_name

            from        hierarchical_table

            where       connect_by_isleaf = 1

            connect by  parent_entity_code = prior entity_code

            start with  entity_code = 100  
            ) h

            join client_table c

            on   c.entity_code  =
                 h.Developer_entity_code 

order by    h.Manager_entity_code  
           ,h.Team_Lead_entity_code
           ,h.Developer_entity_code
;
```

---

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| MANAGER_ENTITY_CODE | MANAGER_ENTITY_NAME | TEAM_LEAD_ENTITY_CODE | TEAM_LEAD_ENTITY_NAME | DEVELOPER_ENTITY_CODE | DEVELOPER_ENTITY_NAME | CLIENT_NAME |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
|                 100 | Mack                |                   200 | Shail                 |                   500 | Neha                  | Tata        |
|                 100 | Mack                |                   300 | Jack                  |                   600 | Rocky                 | Rel         |
|                 100 | Mack                |                   300 | Jack                  |                   600 | Rocky                 | Voda        |
|                 100 | Mack                |                   300 | Jack                  |                   600 | Rocky                 | Airtel      |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

For `start with  entity_code = 300`

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| MANAGER_ENTITY_CODE | MANAGER_ENTITY_NAME | TEAM_LEAD_ENTITY_CODE | TEAM_LEAD_ENTITY_NAME | DEVELOPER_ENTITY_CODE | DEVELOPER_ENTITY_NAME | CLIENT_NAME |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| (null)              | (null)              |                   300 | Jack                  |                   600 | Rocky                 | Airtel      |
| (null)              | (null)              |                   300 | Jack                  |                   600 | Rocky                 | Voda        |
| (null)              | (null)              |                   300 | Jack                  |                   600 | Rocky                 | Rel         |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: thank you Dudu, you made my day. Both your solutions are working fine. As i have lakhs of data to process using hierarchy which solution should i prefer (I think regex one takes more time to execute).

Answer (score 4):

In your query results you expect certain roles to have a certain position in the hierarchy. Manager is first level, team leaders are second, developers are third. So you can treat your hierarchical table as if it were not. This makes the query very readable:

```
with manager    as (select * from employee_hierarchy where entity_role = 'Manager')
   , teamleader as (select * from employee_hierarchy where entity_role = 'Team-Lead')
   , developer  as (select * from employee_hierarchy where entity_role = 'Developer')
select
  m.entity_code as manager_entity_code,
  m.entity_name as manager_entity_name,
  t.entity_code as team_lead_entity_code,
  t.entity_name as team_lead__entity_name,
  d.entity_code as developer_entity_code,
  d.entity_name as developer_entity_name,
  c.client_name
from manager m
join teamleader t on t.parent_entity_code = m.entity_code
join developer d on d.parent_entity_code = t.entity_code
left join client_table c on c.entity_code = d.entity_code;
```

And if you want to restrict the results to the department of team leader Shail, simply add the according `WHERE` clause:

```
where t.entity_name = 'Shail'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do this, using joins. An alternative is to combine the two tables and do a hierarchical query - but that is really the same thing (a hierarchical query is nothing but a recursive self-join).

```
with
     hierarchical_table ( entity_code, entity_name, entity_role, parent_entity_code ) as (
       select 100, 'Mack' , 'Manager',   cast (null as number) from dual union all
       select 200, 'Shail', 'Team-Lead', 100                   from dual union all
       select 300, 'Jack' , 'Team-Lead', 100                   from dual union all
       select 400, 'Teju' , 'Developer', 200                   from dual union all
       select 500, 'Neha' , 'Developer', 200                   from dual union all
       select 600, 'Rocky', 'Developer', 300                   from dual
     ),
     client_table ( entity_code, client_name, address ) as (
       select 600, 'Voda'  , 'Pune'   from dual union all
       select 600, 'Rel'   , 'Mumbai' from dual union all
       select 600, 'Airtel', 'Pune'   from dual union all
       select 500, 'Tata'  , 'Mumbai' from dual
     )
-- end of test data (not part of the solution)
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE; use your actual table names
select   h1.entity_code as   manager_code, h1.entity_name as   manager_name,
         h2.entity_code as  teamlead_code, h2.entity_name as  teamlead_name,
         h3.entity_code as developer_code, h3.entity_name as developer_name,
         c.client_name
from     hierarchical_table h1 left join hierarchical_table h2
                                      on h2.parent_entity_code = h1.entity_code
                               left join hierarchical_table h3
                                      on h3.parent_entity_code = h2.entity_code
                               left join client_table c
                                      on c.entity_code = h3.entity_code
where    h1.parent_entity_code is null
order by manager_code, teamlead_code, developer_code, client_name
;
```

**Output**:

```
MANAGER_CODE MANAGER_NAME TEAMLEAD_CODE TEAMLEAD_NAME DEVELOPER_CODE DEVELOPER_NAME CLIENT
------------ ------------ ------------- ------------- -------------- -------------- ------
         100 Mack                   200 Shail                    400 Teju
         100 Mack                   200 Shail                    500 Neha           Tata
         100 Mack                   300 Jack                     600 Rocky          Airtel
         100 Mack                   300 Jack                     600 Rocky          Rel
         100 Mack                   300 Jack                     600 Rocky          Voda

5 rows selected.
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but in the above solution the cycle always starts from root element that is where parent_entity_code is null and column name is constant, But i have scenarios where the cycle could start from in between hierarchy and i will have to display the hierarchy from that point to lowermost point thats why i had mentioned to keep the column name as role name.

Comment: @ShaileshYadav - I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I assume by "cycle" you mean "tree" (I don't see any cycles in any of this). Then you are commenting about the column names. Of course, you control what the column names are (in the query itself); I used exactly your names, I just left "entity" out (and I did that only so that the **Output** fits on screen without scrolling). The bit about having to run the query from an intermediate point - what does have to do with column names? (Probably nothing.)

Comment: @ShaileshYadav - And if there is anything else this query doesn't do because it doesn't handle those situations - where is the discussion of those other situations in your original post? Or are you changing your requirement AFTER we solved your original question completely? That's not how it works!

Comment: @ShaileshYadav - ... and, I just checked and I see that you DID edit your post and you changed the requirement, AFTER you got a complete solution to your original problem and without saying what you did. That is bullshit. Good luck!

Comment: hi... i voted for your answer, and i did edited the last line of my question as it was not specific, sorry for the same... but my requirement is to get the hierarchical data from the node which user will submit that means it will not always be the root node.

Answer (score 2):

```
select      regexp_substr (h.entity,'Manager~([^~]*)~'         ,1,1,'',1)   as Manager_entity_code         
           ,regexp_substr (h.entity,'Manager~([^~]*)~([^,]*)'  ,1,1,'',2)   as Manager_entity_name  
           ,regexp_substr (h.entity,'Team-Lead~([^~]*)~'       ,1,1,'',1)   as Team_Lead_entity_code
           ,regexp_substr (h.entity,'Team-Lead~([^~]*)~([^,]*)',1,1,'',2)   as Team_Lead_entity_name
           ,regexp_substr (h.entity,'Developer~([^~]*)~'       ,1,1,'',1)   as Developer_entity_code
           ,regexp_substr (h.entity,'Developer~([^~]*)~([^,]*)',1,1,'',2)   as Developer_entity_name
           ,c.client_name

from       (select      sys_connect_by_path (entity_role || '~' || entity_code || '~' || entity_name,',')  as entity
                       ,entity_code

            from        hierarchical_table

            where       connect_by_isleaf = 1

            connect by  parent_entity_code = prior entity_code

            start with  entity_code = 200  
            ) h

            join client_table c

            on   c.entity_code  =
                 h.entity_code 

order by    Manager_entity_code  
           ,Team_Lead_entity_code
           ,Developer_entity_code
;
```

---

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| MANAGER_ENTITY_CODE | MANAGER_ENTITY_NAME | TEAM_LEAD_ENTITY_CODE | TEAM_LEAD_ENTITY_NAME | DEVELOPER_ENTITY_CODE | DEVELOPER_ENTITY_NAME | CLIENT_NAME |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
|                 100 | Mack                |                   200 | Shail                 |                   500 | Neha                  | Tata        |
|                 100 | Mack                |                   300 | Jack                  |                   600 | Rocky                 | Rel         |
|                 100 | Mack                |                   300 | Jack                  |                   600 | Rocky                 | Voda        |
|                 100 | Mack                |                   300 | Jack                  |                   600 | Rocky                 | Airtel      |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

For `start with  entity_code = 600`

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| MANAGER_ENTITY_CODE | MANAGER_ENTITY_NAME | TEAM_LEAD_ENTITY_CODE | TEAM_LEAD_ENTITY_NAME | DEVELOPER_ENTITY_CODE | DEVELOPER_ENTITY_NAME | CLIENT_NAME |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| (null)              | (null)              | (null)                | (null)                |                   600 | Rocky                 | Airtel      |
| (null)              | (null)              | (null)                | (null)                |                   600 | Rocky                 | Voda        |
| (null)              | (null)              | (null)                | (null)                |                   600 | Rocky                 | Rel         |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
```